# How to run an Object Detection prediction on a MobileNet SSD model hosted on SageMaker

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker, mobilenet

I trained a MobileNet v1 SSD model using AWS SageMaker and it trained perfectly.  I have an export/Servo/xxx/saved_graph (a tflite model derived from the checkpoints worked perfectly on an IoT device.)    The model deployed on SageMaker as an endpoint without a problem.   My problem is, I don't know how to feed images into the model endpoint.  (Which presumably is the same as asking how do I feed data into a served model?)

When I query the model (below), I see the input signature is 'serialized_example'.   So, I'm assuming I need a serialized example.   That's where I run out of talent.

I need help understanding how to convert jpg file into a serialized example.  Or how can I use a tfrecord.

```
saved_model_cli show --dir {MODEL_PATH} --tag_set serve --signature_def tensorflow/serving/predict
```

yields (I omitted the outputs):

```
  inputs['serialized_example'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: ()
      name: tf_example:0
```

I have a Dataset but don't know how to get the right class -

```
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_file_list)
example_decoder = TfExampleDecoder()
decoded_dataset = raw_dataset.map(example_decoder.decode)
```

if I enumerate across a decoded dataset, how can I feed the data into my model?

```
for n, e in enumerate(decoded_dataset.take(4)):
   what do I do with e - which looks like:

<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {image: (?, ?, 3), source_id: (), key: (), filename: (), groundtruth_boxes: (?, 4), groundtruth_area: (?,), groundtruth_is_crowd: (?,), groundtruth_difficult: (?,), groundtruth_group_of: (?,), groundtruth_weights: (?,), groundtruth_classes: (?,), groundtruth_image_classes: (?,), original_image_spatial_shape: (2,)}, types: {image: tf.uint8, source_id: tf.string, key: tf.string, filename: tf.string, groundtruth_boxes: tf.float32, groundtruth_area: tf.float32, groundtruth_is_crowd: tf.bool, groundtruth_difficult: tf.int64, groundtruth_group_of: tf.int64, groundtruth_weights: tf.float32, groundtruth_classes: tf.int64, groundtruth_image_classes: tf.int64, original_image_spatial_shape: tf.int32}>
```

Comment: I will go outer of this topic but need to ask. Is there any guide to train mobilenet-SSD with SageMaker ?